# How to have correct 2D bouncing balls of the walls physics? And also so it works same with low fps?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics

I would like to have 2D bouncy balls physics.
It is with Unity Physics 2D. I set bounciness 1 and friction 0.
I tested it on flat floor and here are issues I see:

1. The balls keep jump higher and higher.
2. Balls stuck at the wall. Skip to 0:40 you'll see there are several balls lose their X movement and stay vertically at the right wall.

Ball:
[Ball Rigidbody2D & Collider2D screenshot components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81W9a.png),
[Ball physics material screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOTD0.png)

Walls:
[Wall Collider2D screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKcs5.png)

Video showing the balls(starts at 0:06)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fIo84AMMbgI&feature=emb_logo

What should I do? to have

1. That balls don't start to jump higher and higher. I tried to set less bouncy like 0.99 but it works different with lags on lower fps. So it seems not a solution.
2. That balls don't lose their X movement of the walls.

Comment: Please show us the code that handles collisions. Without more information, we cannot effectively answer the question.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou There is no code in this example. Physics is calculated by Rigidbody2D and Collider2D components in Unity engine. Physics material on the balls. The question is how to configure them correctly

Comment: Show us how you have configured them, then.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Hey sorry for causing confusion. Here are Unity components I am using. I also tried to select different configurations of the components. But yet could not make еру balls behave without mentioned issues.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/81W9a.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOTD0.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKcs5.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A guy on Unity forum told that the balls stop at walls might be the [Physics2D.velocityThreshold](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D-velocityThreshold.html) set above zero. We checked and it solved the issue that balls stop X movement near walls.
He also said box2d works only approx so maybe no way to make balls bounce 100% precise.
So maybe I will have to forget about 100% bouncy balls.